# Nice TTY window borders in 24.4

Tags: window, faces, display, buffer-display-table

I've seen snippets like this:

```el
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'vertical-border (make-glyph-code ?┃))
```

That claim to make emacs use a prettier window divider character. However, `standard-display-table` is `nil` in a `emacs24.4 -Q`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs of `standard-display-table` refer to `buffer-display-table` which mentions that you can create display tables with `make-display-table` if necessary.

This means the following should work:

```
(let ((display-table (or standard-display-table (make-display-table))))
  (set-display-table-slot display-table 'vertical-border (make-glyph-code ?┃))
  (setq standard-display-table display-table))
```

Comment: Thanks. I _though_ something like this existed, I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to fiddle with a display table. Just customize face `window-divider`: `M-x customize-face window-divider`.

I use a `Blue` foreground attribute, for example. Here is a screenshot, with scroll bars turned off:

[image]

Oops. I see now that you are interested in TTY, not graphics. In that case, you can try customizing face `vertical-border`, giving it, for example, a `width` attribute value of `narrow`.  Here is a screenshot of that:

[image]